haw return only true without false after count
enter image description here
SELECT actors, s_id_actors, COUNT(s_id_actors) > 2
FROM films, actors
join actor_film
ON id_actors = s_id_actors
WHERE id_films = s_id_film and years = 2016
GROUP BY s_id_actors, actors
i need return true without folse
I don't know what to write here. I've been studying sql for the first week

Ensure image description and code formatting is proper.
